# Weil's Riemann Hypothesis for dummies?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request

[Weil's Riemann Hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures) is a deep result that I don't fully understand, but it has understandable corollaries which interest me. For example:

(a) For any projective curve $X$ satisfying certain conditions, the number $N$ of points in $X$ with coordinates in $\mathrm{GF}(q)$ satisfies $|N-(q+1)|\leq\mathrm{const}\cdot\sqrt{q}$. (The deviation is $0$ when $X$ is a projective line.)

(b) For any nontrivial multiplicative character $\chi$ on $\mathrm{GF}(q)$ and any polynomial $f$ of degree $n$ satisfying certain conditions, we have

$$\bigg|\sum_{x\in\mathrm{GF}(q)}\chi(f(x))\bigg|\leq(n-1)\sqrt{q}.$$

Questions:

1. Is there a reference (legible to an English-speaking non-expert in the field) which gives the rigorous statements of these corollaries? In particular, I would like conditions which one can verify without a background in algebraic geometry.
2. Are there other corollaries of Weil's Riemann Hypothesis which are also widely understandable? **EDIT:** I'm mostly interested in the Riemann Hypothesis, but I'm also happy to learn understandable consequences of the other Weil conjectures and related results.

Comment: Statements are given in Wolfgang Schmidt's book, Equations over Finite Fields, Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics 536. (a) is on page 2, (b) is on page 43.

Comment: Are you interested specifically in consequences of the *Riemann hypothesis* for curves, or in any aspects of the Weil conjectures for curves (of which RH is the hardest part, but also includes rationality and a functional equation for the zeta-function of the curve)? What about for higher-dimensional varieties? I ask because one of the answers below is an application of the rationality of the zeta-function for higher-dimensional varieties, not involving RH for that zeta-function. Is that a kind of consequence you're interested in too? It'd be good to clarify this in your question.

Comment: You might like to look into Stichtenoth's book "Algebraic function fields and codes", which gives a completely self-contained exposition of the Riemann hypothesis for curves and all material leading up to it.  It is completely algebraic and non-geometric, but it does get to Weil's Riemann hypothesis very quickly starting from nothing.

Answer (score 16):

Here are the statements from Schmidt's book (as pointed to in my comment).

(a) Suppose $f(x,y)$ is a polynomial of total degree $d$, with coefficients in the field of $q$ elements and with $N$ zeros with coordinates in that field. Suppose $f(x,y)$ is absolutely irreducible, that is, irreducible not only over the field of $q$ elements, but also over every algebraic extension thereof. Then $$|N-q|\le2g\sqrt q+c_1(d)$$ where $g$ is the genus of the curve $f(x,y)=0$.

I am not up to explaining "genus" without algebraic geometry, but it is known that $g\le(d-1)(d-2)/2$, so if you are willing to settle for $$|N-q|\le(d-1)(d-2)\sqrt q+c_1(d)$$ then I think you have what you are after.

(b) Let $\chi$ be a multiplicative character of order $d>1$. Suppose that $f(x)$, a polynomial in one variable over the field of $q$ elements, has $m$ distinct zeros, and is not a $d$th power. Then $$\Bigl|\sum_{x\in{\bf F}_q}\chi(f(x))\Bigr|\le(m-1)\sqrt q$$

Comment: Thanks! Do we know what $c_1(d)$ is, or do we have a bound in terms of $d$?

Comment: @Dustin: yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 9):

This is an explicit version of part (a) of Gerry Myerson's answer.  If $f(x,y)$ is an absolutely irreducible polynomial in $\mathbf{F}_q[x,y]$ of total degree $d>0$, and $N$ is the number of zeroes of $f(x,y)$ in $\mathbf{F}_q\times\mathbf{F}_q$, then
$$
q+1-(d-1)(d-2)\sqrt{q}-d\le N\le q+1+(d-1)(d-2)\sqrt{q}.
$$
Likewise, if $f(x,y,z)$ is an absolutely irreducible homogeneous polynomial in $\mathbf{F}_q[x,y,z]$ of total degree $d>0$, and $N$ is the number of zeroes of $f(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbf{P}^2(\mathbf{F}_q)$, then
$$
\lvert N-(q+1)\rvert\le (d-1)(d-2)\sqrt{q}.
$$
These results comprise Corollary 2 in the paper "The number of points on a singular curve over a finite field" by Leep and Yeomans (Arch. Math. 63 (1994), 420-426).

Comment: This is just what I am looking for. So anyone can understand the precise meaning even without knowing much about algebraic geometry. I also find the paper by Leep and Yeomans cited by you. Indeed they proved this elementary version in terms of polynomials in the paper. That's perfect for me although I didn't ask the question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Joy-Joy: I'm happy this was useful for you, thanks for the feedback.  You might want to be aware that the literature also contains many incorrect versions of these results; so you should proceed with caution when using other versions.  Some of these mistakes are spelled out in the remark after Lemma 2.2 in my paper with Peter Mueller "Low-degree planar monomials in characteristic two" (J.Algebraic Combinatorics 42 (2015), 695-699).

Answer (score 8):

For your second question, here is a corollary of the Weil conjectures that can be widely understood and verified:

Let $\{f_i(T_1,...,T_n)\}_i$ be a "good" system of homogeneous polynomials ("good" means they define a smooth connected projective variety) defined over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, and denote by $N_s$ the number of their solutions in $\mathbb{F}_{q^s}$. Then the rationality part of the Weil conjectures implies that all the $\{N_s\}_s$ are determined by the first few finitely many $N_s$ (for example, for a curve of genus $g$, the $N_1,...,N_{2g}$ determines all $N_s$).

This can be seen by expanding the rational form of zeta function into series and compare the coefficients by linear recursion relation.

Comment: Don’t you mean the first $g$ numbers rather than the first $2g$?

Comment: @Lubin: it looks like only the rationality (and degree of numerator) is being used here, not also the functional equation.

Comment: @KConrad, ah yes, right you are.